# Use Greasemonkey to block CKEditor in "Invision Power Board" forums?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, greasemonkey, invision-power-board

I'm quite sick of having to deal with *CKEditor* in [*Invision Power Board*](http://www.invisionpower.com/apps/board/) (IPB) and I'd like to use another editor.

I have already the other editor ready in a Greasemonkey script. The problem now is that I don't know how to prevent CKEditor from loading or just turn it off after loading so that my editor may execute in its place.

How do I "turn off" CKEditor?

For the ones who need:

[Here's an IPB forum using CKEditor.](http://community.invisionpower.com/index.php?app=forums&module=post&section=post&do=new_post&f=305) It requires registering, though.

[Here's a demo forum](http://www.forum-software.org/demo/ipboard), but it's currently offline.

Comment: @BrockAdams I added the stuff you requested. The target I have is not in english, so I believe it is not useful for you. Anyway, I did my best to get you an example of the kind of code you are expected to find in that page.

Comment: Thanks.  The language is not important, the HTML/JS of the page is.     The version of board SW could be important too.

Comment: I don't know the code, unfortunately...

Comment: That's why you link to the page, we can see the HTML then (and the IPB version and the CKE version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the later versions of IPB (not the earlier free ones) if you block the load of the CKEditor javascript, IPB will present you with a plain `<textarea>` instead.

In Firefox+Greasemonkey, you can block the CKEditor javascript with [the brilliant *checkForBadJavascripts* utility](https://gist.github.com/2620135).  Like so:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Block CKEditor on the selected site(s)
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2620135/checkForBadJavascripts.js
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

checkForBadJavascripts ( [
    [true,  /ckeditor/i,  null ]
] );
```

When you do that, IPB presents you with a `<textarea>` with class `ipsEditor_textarea`.  **For example:**

```
<textarea class="ipsEditor_textarea input_text" name="Post" id="editor_50b6f145efdd7">
</textarea>
```

You can then attach your editor to that.

Comment: Hehe!!! That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! I already attached the editor I want and adapted to many situations!